# Deleted Locale, Entries all gone now

Tags: entries, localization, database

I deleted a locale and checked to transfer all its contents to a different locale, but now the other locale still shows no entries.  I'm sure all the entries are still in the database.

Any help?

Comment: Was the section the entries were in enabled for both locales to begin with? Can you describe how it was setup?

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Have exactly the same situation right now, and urgently need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem for assets and globals.

When craft thinks there are no globals, the entire tab isn't showed.
For the globals i created a new temporary global, so i could access the existing (hidden) ones (they were still connected to one locale).
After that i could open and save them.
After saving they worked for other locales again.

I later found out that setting the admin account to the locale that is working also allows access. Opening and saving each entry works.

Still did not find a solution when content is disconnected from all locales.

Comment: I just put a backup back and changed the locale in the db by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Change the preferred locale to the new locale where you want to transfer your content. Settings - > My account -> Preferred Locale.